# Want to enter cyrillic in easy drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

i downloaded a html5 crossword puzzle, but the easy drop script dont accept cyrillic and latin words. I want to enter latin and cyrillic words, but the plugin blocked this. here's the script:

```
(function($){

// to track if the mouse button is pressed
var isMouseDown    = false;

// to track the current element being dragged
var currentElement = null;

// callback holders
var dropCallbacks = {};
var dragCallbacks = {};

// bubbling status
var bubblings = {};

// global position records
var lastMouseX;
var lastMouseY;
var lastElemTop;
var lastElemLeft;

// track element dragStatus
var dragStatus = {};    

// if user is holding any handle or not
var holdingHandler = false;

// returns the mouse (cursor) current position
$.getMousePosition = function(e){
    var posx = 0;
    var posy = 0;

    if (!e) var e = window.event;

    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
        posx = e.pageX;
        posy = e.pageY;
    }
    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
        posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop  + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    return { 'x': posx, 'y': posy };
};

// updates the position of the current element being dragged
$.updatePosition = function(e) {
    var pos = $.getMousePosition(e);

    var spanX = (pos.x - lastMouseX);
    var spanY = (pos.y - lastMouseY);

    $(currentElement).css("top",  (lastElemTop + spanY));
    $(currentElement).css("left", (lastElemLeft + spanX));
};

// when the mouse is moved while the mouse button is pressed
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if(isMouseDown && dragStatus[currentElement.id] != 'false'){
        // update the position and call the registered function
        $.updatePosition(e);
        if(dragCallbacks[currentElement.id] != undefined){
            dragCallbacks[currentElement.id](e, currentElement);
        }

        return false;
    }
});

// when the mouse button is released
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if(isMouseDown && dragStatus[currentElement.id] != 'false'){
        isMouseDown = false;
        if(dropCallbacks[currentElement.id] != undefined){
            dropCallbacks[currentElement.id](e, currentElement);
        }

        return false;
    }
});

// register the function to be called while an element is being dragged
$.fn.ondrag = function(callback){
    return this.each(function(){
        dragCallbacks[this.id] = callback;
    });
};

// register the function to be called when an element is dropped
$.fn.ondrop = function(callback){
    return this.each(function(){
        dropCallbacks[this.id] = callback;
    });
};

// disable the dragging feature for the element
$.fn.dragOff = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        dragStatus[this.id] = 'off';
    });
};

// enable the dragging feature for the element
$.fn.dragOn = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        dragStatus[this.id] = 'on';
    });
};

// set a child element as a handler
$.fn.setHandler = function(handlerId){
    return this.each(function(){
        var draggable = this;

        // enable event bubbling so the user can reach the handle
        bubblings[this.id] = true;

        // reset cursor style
        $(draggable).css("cursor", "");

        // set current drag status
        dragStatus[draggable.id] = "handler";

        // change handle cursor type
        $("#"+handlerId).css("cursor", "move"); 

        // bind event handler
        $("#"+handlerId).mousedown(function(e){
            holdingHandler = true;
            $(draggable).trigger('mousedown', e);
        });

        // bind event handler
        $("#"+handlerId).mouseup(function(e){
            holdingHandler = false;
        });
    });
}

// set an element as draggable - allowBubbling enables/disables event bubbling
$.fn.easydrag = function(allowBubbling){

    return this.each(function(){

        // if no id is defined assign a unique one
        if(undefined == this.id || !this.id.length) this.id = "easydrag"+(new Date().getTime());

        // save event bubbling status
        bubblings[this.id] = allowBubbling ? true : false;

        // set dragStatus 
        dragStatus[this.id] = "on";

        // change the mouse pointer
        $(this).css("cursor", "move");

        // when an element receives a mouse press
        $(this).mousedown(function(e){

            // just when "on" or "handler"
            if((dragStatus[this.id] == "off") || (dragStatus[this.id] == "handler" && !holdingHandler))
                return bubblings[this.id];

            // set it as absolute positioned
            $(this).css("position", "absolute");

            // set z-index
            $(this).css("z-index", parseInt( new Date().getTime()/1000 ));

            // update track variables
            isMouseDown    = true;
            currentElement = this;

            // retrieve positioning properties
            var pos    = $.getMousePosition(e);
            lastMouseX = pos.x;
            lastMouseY = pos.y;

            lastElemTop  = this.offsetTop;
            lastElemLeft = this.offsetLeft;

            $.updatePosition(e);

            return bubblings[this.id];
        });
    });
};

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for help :)
Modify the code format, so it is more clear

Comment: This script implements drag and drop functionality. Not sure what it has to do with any crossword puzzles.

Comment: It drag and drops the caption of crossword,but has problem this plugin blocks cyrillic

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted does any modification of text.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the actual text of elements, so I don't see how it "blocks" cyrillic. What is the actual problem you are having?